# GCC 4.8.1 failed complilation

Tags: compile, gcc

I am using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bit. This is the error message:

```
checking for x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc... /home/hoangtu/Downloads/gcc-4.8.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/xgcc -B/home/hoangtu/Downloads/gcc-4.8.1/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include  -m32
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/hoangtu/Downloads/gcc-4.8.1/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/32/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [configure-stage1-target-libgcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hoangtu/Downloads/gcc-4.8.1'
make[1]: *** [stage1-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hoangtu/Downloads/gcc-4.8.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Is Ubuntu 13.04 too new for gcc to detect (it detected x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc). I compiled fine with Linux Mint 14 32 bit.

Edit: Checking config.log, it looks like there's a failed test:

```
configure:5876: gcc -o conftest -g -O2      conftest.c  -lisl >&5
conftest.c:10:25: fatal error: isl/version.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:5876: $? = 1
configure: program exited with status 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <isl/version.h>
|    #include <string.h>
| int
| main ()
| {
| if (strncmp (isl_version (), "isl-0.10", strlen ("isl-0.10")) != 0)
|      return 1;
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:5885: result: no
configure:5905: checking for version 0.11 of ISL
configure:5924: gcc -o conftest -g -O2      conftest.c  -lisl >&5
conftest.c:10:25: fatal error: isl/version.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
configure:5924: $? = 1
configure: program exited with status 1
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| #define LT_OBJDIR ".libs/"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| #include <isl/version.h>
|    #include <string.h>
| int
| main ()
| {
| if (strncmp (isl_version (), "isl-0.11", strlen ("isl-0.11")) != 0)
|      return 1;
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:5933: result: no
configure:7090: checking for default BUILD_CONFIG
configure:7122: result: bootstrap-debug
configure:7611: checking for bison
configure:7627: found /usr/bin/bison
configure:7638: result: bison -y
configure:7658: checking for bison
configure:7674: found /usr/bin/bison
configure:7685: result: bison
configure:7705: checking for gm4
configure:7735: result: no
configure:7705: checking for gnum4
configure:7735: result: no
configure:7705: checking for m4
configure:7721: found /usr/bin/m4
configure:7732: result: m4
configure:7752: checking for flex
configure:7768: found /usr/bin/flex
configure:7779: result: flex
configure:7800: checking for flex
configure:7816: found /usr/bin/flex
configure:7827: result: flex
configure:7847: checking for makeinfo
configure:7863: found /usr/bin/makeinfo
configure:7874: result: makeinfo
configure:7908: checking for expect
configure:7938: result: no
configure:7957: checking for runtest
configure:7987: result: no
configure:8102: checking for ar
configure:8118: found /usr/bin/ar
configure:8129: result: ar
configure:8243: checking for as
configure:8259: found /usr/bin/as
configure:8270: result: as
configure:8384: checking for dlltool
configure:8414: result: no
configure:8525: checking for ld
configure:8541: found /usr/bin/ld
configure:8552: result: ld
configure:8666: checking for lipo
configure:8696: result: no
configure:8807: checking for nm
configure:8823: found /usr/bin/nm
configure:8834: result: nm
configure:8948: checking for ranlib
configure:8964: found /usr/bin/ranlib
configure:8975: result: ranlib
configure:9084: checking for strip
configure:9100: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:9111: result: strip
configure:9220: checking for windres
configure:9250: result: no
configure:9361: checking for windmc
configure:9391: result: no
configure:9502: checking for objcopy
configure:9518: found /usr/bin/objcopy
configure:9529: result: objcopy
configure:9643: checking for objdump
configure:9659: found /usr/bin/objdump
configure:9670: result: objdump
configure:9784: checking for readelf
configure:9800: found /usr/bin/readelf
configure:9811: result: readelf
configure:9964: checking for cc
configure:9980: found /usr/bin/cc
configure:9991: result: cc
configure:10125: checking for c++
configure:10141: found /usr/bin/c++
configure:10152: result: c++
configure:10286: checking for gcc
configure:10302: found /usr/bin/gcc
configure:10313: result: gcc
configure:10442: checking for gcj
configure:10472: result: no
configure:10603: checking for gfortran
configure:10619: found /usr/bin/gfortran
configure:10630: result: gfortran
configure:10764: checking for gccgo
configure:10794: result: no
configure:10855: checking for ar
configure:10888: result: no
configure:11005: checking for ar
configure:11021: found /usr/bin/ar
configure:11032: result: ar
configure:11085: checking for as
configure:11118: result: no
configure:11235: checking for as
configure:11251: found /usr/bin/as
configure:11262: result: as
configure:11315: checking for dlltool
configure:11348: result: no
configure:11465: checking for dlltool
configure:11495: result: no
configure:11545: checking for ld
configure:11578: result: no
configure:11695: checking for ld
configure:11711: found /usr/bin/ld
configure:11722: result: ld
configure:11775: checking for lipo
configure:11808: result: no
configure:11925: checking for lipo
configure:11955: result: no
configure:12005: checking for nm
configure:12038: result: no
configure:12155: checking for nm
configure:12171: found /usr/bin/nm
configure:12182: result: nm
configure:12235: checking for objdump
configure:12268: result: no
configure:12385: checking for objdump
configure:12401: found /usr/bin/objdump
configure:12412: result: objdump
configure:12465: checking for ranlib
configure:12498: result: no
configure:12615: checking for ranlib
configure:12631: found /usr/bin/ranlib
configure:12642: result: ranlib
configure:12695: checking for readelf
configure:12728: result: no
configure:12845: checking for readelf
configure:12861: found /usr/bin/readelf
configure:12872: result: readelf
configure:12925: checking for strip
configure:12958: result: no
configure:13075: checking for strip
configure:13091: found /usr/bin/strip
configure:13102: result: strip
configure:13155: checking for windres
configure:13188: result: no
configure:13305: checking for windres
configure:13335: result: no
configure:13385: checking for windmc
configure:13418: result: no
configure:13535: checking for windmc
configure:13565: result: no
configure:13593: checking where to find the target ar
configure:13626: result: host tool
configure:13635: checking where to find the target as
configure:13668: result: host tool
configure:13677: checking where to find the target cc
configure:13700: result: just compiled
configure:13719: checking where to find the target c++
configure:13745: result: just compiled
configure:13764: checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++
configure:13790: result: just compiled
configure:13809: checking where to find the target dlltool
configure:13842: result: host tool
configure:13851: checking where to find the target gcc
configure:13874: result: just compiled
configure:13893: checking where to find the target gcj
configure:13919: result: just compiled
configure:13938: checking where to find the target gfortran
configure:13964: result: just compiled
configure:13983: checking where to find the target gccgo
configure:14019: result: host tool
configure:14028: checking where to find the target ld
configure:14061: result: host tool
configure:14070: checking where to find the target lipo
configure:14092: result: host tool
configure:14101: checking where to find the target nm
configure:14134: result: host tool
configure:14143: checking where to find the target objdump
configure:14176: result: host tool
configure:14185: checking where to find the target ranlib
configure:14218: result: host tool
configure:14227: checking where to find the target readelf
configure:14260: result: host tool
configure:14269: checking where to find the target strip
configure:14302: result: host tool
configure:14311: checking where to find the target windres
configure:14344: result: host tool
configure:14353: checking where to find the target windmc
configure:14386: result: host tool
configure:14423: checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles
configure:14432: result: no
configure:14643: creating ./config.status
```

I will try to install libisl to see how it goes.

Comment: Most likely not "too new". What's the last test output in `config.log`?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to compile?

Comment: @Ramhound Of course gcc as a whole

Comment: @honk Updated config.log output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to detect the missing dependency and fixed it: check config.log output to see what libraries are missing and install it. For example, check the config.log in the edit section in my first post; look at a few lines the start, I was missing library isl. I installed it and the problem was solved.

You could do the same. although I ran into another error later that I had to disable multilib (--disable-multilib).

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "honk's comment?" I'm not seeing it here, and would really like to be able to solve this problem.

Comment: "honk's comment" refers to one of the comments written by honk to my first post. You can look above. You should check config.log output to see what library you are missing and install it. You can check the `config.log` in the edit section in my first post: look at a few lines the start, I was missing library  `isl`. I installed it and the problem was solved. You could do the same.

Comment: No comment by @honk is visible. Perhaps it's been deleted?

Comment: Incidentally, thanks for providing the answer in that comment. Meant to say that. If you put it in the actual answer portion, I'll upvote you.

Comment: @mohawkjohn I edited it to make this answer better for future reference. Probably the comment was deleted by the author, so I removed it from my answer.

Comment: Can you post as to where to find the `config.log` file and how to find it?

Comment: @WebQube It is right in the directory where you run `configure`.

Comment: I don't see it my console. can you be a little more specific please?

Comment: What OS are you using? The file `config.log` is supposed to be in the same directory where you run `./configure`.